# Lunar contamination by tardigrades

Tags: the-moon, contamination, beresheet

According to this tweet

[image]

the recent crash of Beresheet on the Moon could have spread tardigrades on the Moon surface.

Isn't this a violation of the agreement on preventing contamination of outer worlds with terrestrial life?

Comment: The agreement is about making best effort attempt not to contaminate. That wasn't intentional or negligent contamination.

Comment: related question about the tardigrades in particular: [Why send tardigrades to the moon if we have actively avoided contaminating other worlds?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38014/12102)